# How to find the Outlook Web Access server name based on the login page?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, url

I want to configure an account on my iPhone to use an Outlook Web Access server. I don't know the server name. Is it possible to find the server name based on the OWA login webpage's URL?

Here is an example of Outlook Web Access logon URL:

```
https://email.jwu.edu/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2femail.jwu.edu%2fowa%2f
```

It would be great if someone can demonstrate how to find the server address using the website address above.

**EDIT: 2014-12-05 UTC+0:00 03:51  : (unanswered)**

I think you guys give the correct server name for the example.

However, when I use the method as you suggested, I can't configure my email on iPhone successfully.

The website that I log in to my email is like:

```
https://portal.xxx.org.xxx
```

After I logged in to the Outlook Web Acces, I click "Options" -> "About".

And I found the Outlook Web Access host address which is in the form like:

```
https://yyyyyyy-webmail/owa
```

This seems to be different from the example since `yyyyyyy-webmail` seems not a formal url, right?

On iPhone, when I chose "Email, Contact, Calander" -> "Add Account" -> "Microsoft Exchange", I entered the email account and password and fill the server as `yyyyyyy-webmail`. However, I cannot connect to my ac.

Moreover, I want to mention that I have to first log in to my institution's website and then log in to my Outlook Web Application.

Is there any mistake I make?

Thanks for all helps!

Comment: Why the downvote? Clearly the OP doesn't understand how URLs work. Given that, how could he ask this question or do research on his own any better?

Comment: I agree with @Twisty. For that reason, upvoted to restore it back to 0 votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server will respond by removing everything from owa and on, and not using https:// either.

So the server address will become: `email.jwu.edu`

You should be able to setup email on your iPhone if the administrators have enabled access for it.

Comment: This seems to be the most suitable answer to my first question, so I chose it as the answer. I would really appreciate if someone could answer my follow-up question.

Comment: -1 Not the answer. Specifics for JWU smartphone email setup here: http://helpdesk.jwu.edu/stu_mobile_instruc.htm

Answer (score 1):

The server address is in the link you quoted in your question.

```
https://email.jwu.edu/owa/auth/logon.aspx
```

If you enter the above adress in your browser you will see:

[image]

Comment: That provides a link to the Outlook Web App. He is looking for the url of the server. See my Answer.

Comment: @LPChip "outlook web access" is what he is looking for ... I presume that in his understanding he meant Outlook Web App ... and that is the normal way to get email externally from an Exchange server. It would be unusual if the Admins had configured smtp/pop in addition ...

Answer (score 0):

JWU has a help page on how to configure your phone:

[Email on your mobile](http://helpdesk.jwu.edu/stu_mobile_instruc.htm)

Short answer is:

- Settings
- Mail, Contacts, Calendars
- Exchange
- On Email field, Enter your jwu e-mail address
- Enter Password
- In Description, give a short name for this account

It should just work with that. That's how our Exchange server is configured.